# PHP - include variables

Tags: php, html, variables, include

I have two files on my hosting website:

- Select.php - Contains variables and gets information from a database and works perfectly, I am able to have it write out all the variables.
- rank.html - generic website

I am trying to pull a single variable `$Stouty447` from the Select.php file into my rank.html file.

I have tried:

```
<?php include 'Select.php';
echo $Stouty447;
?>
```

It outputs `$Stouty447;?>` on my webpage.

I have also tried:

```
<?php include 'Select.php' echo "$Stouty447";?>
```

This outputs `"$Stouty447";?>`

Any ideas on where I should go from here or what I should do?

Comment: do a `view source`. if you see `<?php` in there, then your server is broken

Comment: "I am trying to pull a single variable ($Stouty447) from the Select.php file **into my rank.html file.**" -- This wouldn't work. The file extension must be `.php` (unless you use some `AddHandler` magic with `.htaccess`).

Comment: Second code writes a string not your variable. You should write the first code and change your `rank.html` to a PHP page.

Comment: @MahanGM, second one is also a variable (if it is defined). But the line should contain a `;`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`.html` files normally will not be parsed by PHP without modifying the webserver configuration.  Try renaming it to `rank.php`.